# String Array to Integer Array Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, int

I have a string array for an app I am making. It loads an EditText, so I will instead create a dummy one.

`String[] s = ["1","2","3"];`

How would I change String s into an integer array, such as Int i?

`Int[] i = [1,2,3];`

I have tried Integer.parseInt on the string array but it does not work. Does anyone know how to convert string arrays into integer arrays?

Comment: A simple for-loop will work.

Comment: do Integer.parseInt on each element of the array

Comment: Multiply each array value by 1 and it will convert them to integers.

Comment: @DevlshOne sarcastic I hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
string[] s = ["1","2","3"];
int[] i = new int[s.length()];
for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++)
    i[j] = Integer.parseInt(s[j]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept it in "9 Minutes" :P